# Kill a subprocess.Popen child with CTRL+c

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

If I type this command in a terminal, as user `root`, for say a user `bob`:

```
su - bob -c "cd /home ; ping www.google.com"
```

It pings continuously until I press `CTRL+c`. I am trying to mimic a similar behaviour. My setup script runs before I can have pexpect and other things installed. The ping is running in a child of the sub process because of the `su - bob`. This means that `Popen.kill()` does not work. I have done some research and found some answers here on SO about grouping with a PID and then killing the group.

**Question**: I would like to understand why `communicate` does not send the `CTRL+c` and kill the subprocess I expected, shows I don't understand some fundamentals.

```
import time
import subprocess

user = 'bob'    
cmd_list = ['su', '-', user, '-c','cd /home/ ; ping www.google.com ; exit']

p = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd_list,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
)
print("Wait 2s...")
time.sleep(2)
print("2s passed.")

try:
    # Send CTRL+c to kill the child process from su -
    p.communicate(input='\0x03', timeout=3)
    print("CTRL+c killed the process")
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('Timeout occured')
p.kill()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.communicate` uses `stdin`, you need to send a signal using `send_signal`.

try this:

```py
import time
import subprocess
import signal

user = 'bob'
cmd_list = ['su', '-', user, '-c','cd /home/ ; ping www.google.com ; exit']

p = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd_list,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
)
print("Wait 2s...")
time.sleep(2)
print("2s passed.")

try:
    # Send CTRL+c to kill the child process from su -
    p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    print("CTRL+c killed the process")
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('Timeout occured')
p.kill()
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. It works, but only if I remove the last line 'p.kill()' which is rather strange??? I crawled the docs but did not understand the type signal had to be, this is a tremendous help.

Comment: In light on sending the kill signal, I think I should now change p.kill() to p.wait()